# How to delete permanent view in Couchdb-Futon

Tags: couchdb-futon

I have got couchdb installed in windows OS.
I created a temporary view using Futon and then saved it to make it permanent.
Now i want to delete this permanent view.
How to achieve this?
Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

You must edit the Design Document in which the view is stored, removing its key from `.views`.

Comment: On the Futon interface, in the view dropdown menu you will see an option to show design documents. select it, edit it, save it.